# OR-Tools - Vehicle routing problem - Prevent dropping nodes from initial solution

Tags: c#, or-tools, vehicle-routing

We have a working VRP example with time and capacity constraint.

Our scenario is as follows:

- we have 5 vehicles
- we're accepting requests for transport from A -> B (like taxi)
- for each new request we run the vrp algorithm which determines whether the solution is feasible. When the solution is feasible we create new schedules of drives for the vehicles.
- When the solution is feasible we let the passenger know that their request is approved
- we use penalty = max.int since we wan't to accept as many passengers as possible

Our problem is that algorithm sometimes when it gets new request, drops some nodes (passengers requests) that we already marked as feasible and added to the vehicle schedule. How to prevent droping nodes that were already added to solution (then in initial solution)?

We tried setting penalty to int.max for nodes from initial solution and slightly smaller penalty to the node we're currently adding. It did reduce the number of events when already confirmed node is later dropped, but it still happens.
We think that partial solutions also aren't the right way since the vehicle must be able to accept passenger B while transporting passenger A if it fits the capacity and time constraints.
Locking vehicle also doesn't look right since it prevents us to add new passengers to solved solution.

We just need a way to somehow prevent certain nodes to be dropped. In our case - nodes that were already once added to solution. In other words - our initial solution can change but must not drop any nodes.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We managed to solve this issue with removing penalty. Since we run the algorithm for each request and our goal is to take as many customers as possible, there was no need to use penalty. When the penalty isn't used or-tools will drop all nodes when the solution isn't feasible. In our case that means if the solution with new request isn't feasible it means that we have to reject the request. Or-tools will drop all nodes but we just skip the part where we save the new solution (in this case - not feasible). That way we still have old feasible result from before saved. And we use this "old" solution for our upcoming requests.